# AWK to filter output

Tags: bash, awk

i'm confusing about this i have a following directory structure

```
ls -d */*
keyspace1/table2           system/peers                  system/sstable_activity                     system_schema/columns
system/IndexInfo           system/prepared_statements    system/transferred_ranges                   system_schema/dropped_columns
system/available_ranges    system/range_xfers            system/views_builds_in_progress             system_schema/functions
system/batches             system/schema_aggregates      system_auth/resource_role_permissons_index  system_schema/indexes
system/batchlog            system/schema_columnfamilies  system_auth/role_members                    system_schema/keyspaces
system/built_views         system/schema_columns         system_auth/role_permissions                system_schema/tables
system/compaction_history  system/schema_functions       system_auth/roles                           system_schema/triggers
system/hints               system/schema_keyspaces       system_distributed/parent_repair_history    system_schema/types
system/local               system/schema_triggers        system_distributed/repair_history           system_schema/views
system/paxos               system/schema_usertypes       system_distributed/view_build_status        system_traces/events
system/peer_events         system/size_estimates         system_schema/aggregates                    system_traces/sessions
```

and i want to exclude all system folder, but the system_schema and other directories must remain!
i've tried to do this using AWK but this doesn't works as i want

```
ls -d */* | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if(($i=="system_schema") || ($i!~"system")) {print $i}}}'
keyspace1/table2
```

this prints other dirs which is ok, but when my system_schema folder? or how can i do it using other UNIX tools?
thanks

Comment: IMHO experts always advice not to parse `ls` output.

Answer (score 0):

With sample `grep` you can do it on this way:

```
ls -d */* | grep -v "^system/"
```

or if you want all records which start with `system`, but not `system/` you can use something like:

```
ls -d */* | grep "^system"|grep -v "^system/"
```

If you want only system_schema and keyspace1 you can use this code:

```
 ls -d */* | egrep "system_schema|keyspace"
```

Comment: Thanks! but it prints all the system_* dirs , but i want to print only system_schema and remains!

Comment: @Joom187, add in your question what exactly do you expect

Comment: Thank you! but for example i have dirs system system_auth system_roles keyspace1, and i want to exclude all the system_  dirs except system_schema and keyspace 1

Comment: thank you so much again! but if i have dirs keyspace1 keyspace2 keyspace3...etc or other dirs? thanks so much again!!

Comment: @Joom187, if you have 2,3,... you can just remove the number from grep. And add the other directories. Sometime direct approach is faster and easier :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207581/discussion-between-joom187-and-romeo-ninov).